# Pre-20th century sources on information theory?

Tags: reference-request, information-theory

What are some pre-19<sup>th</sup> or pre-20<sup>th</sup> century sources on information theory? Do they exist?

Comment: No. Information theory (in Shannon's sense) is a 20th century invention that could not even be formulated before Kolmogorov's formalization of probability in 1933. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/information) says that the word started to be applied to broadcast signals from 1937, Shannon published in 1948.

Comment: There is something in philosophy called semantic information theory that can, arguably, be traced to earlier times. But not by that name and it has little to do with Shannon's theory.

Comment: Prior to Shannon, in a different context  but still in the 20th C, [Fisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher), in his Theory of Statistical Estimation wrote about ""the whole of the information which a sample provides" in the 1920s. This is today called [Fisher Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) and the [Fisher Information Metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information_metric).

Comment: @NickR Nyquist's 1924 "[Certain Factors Affecting Telegraph Speed](https://archive.org/details/bstj3-2-324/page/n5)" is also prior to Shannon, but I'm looking for pre-20th cen., at least.

Comment: Etaoin shrdlu and the Morse code perhaps? That is, letter frequency as a means for optimizing the composition of messages.

Comment: @sand1 Maybe, but I'm looking for things more along the lines of philosophy of information theory.